# Error al insertar datos con Java

Tags: java, sql

Estoy teniendo problemas para hacer un insert a la base de datos. Estoy con un ejercicio donde tengo que seleccionar una fila de un Jtable, de ahí saco la primera columna que es la matricula del coche, y al darle al boton reservar me sale un jdialog para meter el dni del cliente y los dias que lo va a alquilar, al darle al boton aceptar, lo tendría que insertar en la base de datos. La cosa es que parece que no me está cogiendo el valor de la tabla o algo estoy haciendo mal por que me sale el fallo:

***Column count doesn't match value count at row 1***

Este es el metodo

```
public void reserva(){

    int numeroFilas = this.tablaCoches.getSelectedRows().length;
    String dni = this.TextoDniJDialog.getText();
    int dias = Integer.parseInt(this.TextoDiasJDialog.getText());
    if(numeroFilas == -1){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                        "No has seleccionado una fila",
                        "ERROR", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }else{
            String matricula = String.valueOf(model.getValueAt(tablaCoches.getSelectedRow(), 0));
            Connection conexion = Conexion.getInstance().getConnection();

            try {
                String sql = "insert into clientes VALUES(?,?,?)";
                PreparedStatement sentencia = conexion.prepareStatement(sql);

                sentencia.setString(1, matricula);
                sentencia.setString(2, dni);
                sentencia.setInt(3, dias);
                sentencia.executeUpdate();
                System.out.println(sentencia.toString());

                /*  String sql2 = "UPDATE coches set alquilado ='" + 1 + "where matricula = " + dato + "'" ;
            Statement sentencia2 = conexion.createStatement();
            ResultSet resultado2 = sentencia.executeQuery(sql);*/
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                        "Actualizado correctamente",
                        "Informativo", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                System.err.println("Error en el método visualizar");
                System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Berias poner la estructura de la tabla para poder darte una mejor solucion y no solo a supuestos

Comment: Es mejor que especifiques qué se va a insertar dónde, es decir `insert into clientes(matricula,dni, fecha) VALUES(?,?,?)` así tal vez obtengas un error más específico.

Comment: si ejecutas el insert en la base de datos con los mismos valores que desde la aplicación Java ¿te marca el mismo error?

Comment: Por qué hacéis una pregunta y desapareceis? Os merece la pena?

Comment: ¿Podrías compartir el esquema de la tabla? (me refiero al número de campos) Si no aportas explícitamente los campos en el `INSERT` no tendrás la seguridad que se introducirán en el correcto y, además, si tienes campos opcionales (no están definidos como `NOT NULL`) no podrás omitirlos.